# Max(Date) not working for varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have a column 'TransactionDate' of Type 'varchar(15)' and i am trying to get the Max(TransactionDate) using this query

```
Select MAX(TransactionDate) from MyBank
```

The results are fine as long as Year is same (11/12/2010) but as soon as i put some data with year (12/23/2011) , the query still shows the Max. Date of 2010 instead of 2011.

My Data is as shown below

```
Name | Age | TransactionDate | Amount
John | 23  | 12/12/2010      | 2000
Rock | 24  | 12/23/2010      | 1000
Sam  | 29  | 1/2/2011        | 5000
Nomi | 22  | 1/3/2011        | 6000
```

Although the query should return 1/3/2011 but its still returning 12/23/2010.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: You should consider fixing the schema to use the correct datatype, so you get expected results.

Comment: Why are are storing date as varchar(15)? Are you expecting to have to deal with dates up to `12/31/999999999`? Storing dates as strings is space inefficient, makes comparisons and sorting inefficient and means you may well end up with invalid dates in your data.

Comment: if you have one invalid date data in any row, then @jani's query: `Max(cast(TransactionDate as DateTime))` will blow up with an error.  repeat this three times: **never store dates as strings in a database** and then solve the real problem and fix the table.  you'll use unnecessary extra processing power **every time** this query is run, or you could fix it **one time** and save all of that processing power for other users/tasks on your database.

Comment: -1 for actually asking "Max(Date) not working for varchar". Really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to `Max(cast(TransactionDate as DateTime))`

Comment: thats absolutely fantastic. It works. I hope there are no drawbacks of using this cast

Comment: @raziiq: it's costing you in terms of performance quite a bit, since it has to convert all the `TransactionDate` fields to DATETIME and then find the maximum value among them. If `TransactionDate` is a DATE, then why not **MAKE** it a DATETIME in the first place.... you could save yourself a lot of hassle and messy conversions and stuff like that.....

Comment: @raziiq The big drawback is that an index cannot be used. It needs to scan the value for all rows rather than retrieve the first record from an index. This can only be fixed by changing your schema.

Comment: Thought of keeping myself hassle free by not converting the DateTime in vb.net and thought of storing it as a string which is costing me now, i m regretting now. But for now my problem is solved. Thanks to Jani.

Comment: @raziiq - I would suggest biting the bullet and changing to `date` datatype now if SQL Server 2008 or `datetime` for earlier versions. Even storing in `yyyymmdd` format would be an improvement over your current arrangement though.